# Removing overlap while spliting polygon layer with multistring layer

Tags: polygon, splitting, postgresql-9.5

I want to split a polygon layer with multi-string layer, but I found an overlap between polygon after the split. How can I remove the overlap?

```sql
SELECT distinct a.id,a.name,a.id0,a.name0,a.city,a.area,
(ST_Dump(ST_CollectionExtract(ST_MakeValid(ST_Split(a.geom, b.geom)), 3))).geom:: GEOMETRY(POLYGON, 4326) geom
INTO TABLE split_tbl
FROM sublocality_polygon a , split_lines b
WHERE st_intersects(a.geom,b.geom);
```

[image: example]